# Add a flag on the values of rows

Tags: sas, teradata

I have a table (Student_classification) with two columns, Student Number and Subject (example):

```
Student Number         Subject
122                      Biology_Physics
122                      Math
122                      Music
125                      music
125                      geography
298                      Math
298                      Economics
```

My task is to get a new table where:

1. if the student Number has Biology_Physics and (either Math or Music or geography or economics) as Science
2. if the student number has (geography or music) and do not have any other as Humnity/arts
3. if the student has (Math or Economics) and do not have any other as EconomicsEngineering

My final result should be:

```
Student Number        Type
122                    Science
125                    Humanity/arts
298                    EconomicsEngineering
```

However, I get following table which is incorrect:

```
Student_Number             Type
122                         Other
122                         EconomicEngineering
122                         Humanity/arts
125                         Humanity/arts
298                         EconomicEngineering
```

I have written the following code in SAS, but the logics seems incorrect:

```sql
Proc Sql;
create table student_classification as
(
select distinct cust_num,
case
when Subject ='Biology_Physics' and Subject in ('Math' 'Music' 'geography' 'economics') then 'Science'
When Subject in ('geography' 'music') and Subject not in ('Biology_Physics' 'Math' 'economics') then 'Humanity/arts'
When Subject in ('math' 'economics) and subject not in ('Biology_Physics' 'Geography' 'Music') then 'EconomicEngineering'
else 'Other'
end as Type
from Student_classification
Group by student_number, Type
);
quit;
```

My use case is different, but simulating the similar idea here.

Answer (score 0):

You try to compare values from multiple rows, thus you need *conditional aggregation*.

```
select cust_num,
    case 
      -- has Biology_Physics and (either Math or Music or geography or economics) as Science
      when max(case when Subject ='Biology_Physics' then 1 end) = 1
       and max(case when Subject in ('Math', 'Music', 'geography', 'economics') then 1 end) = 1 
      then 'Science'

      -- has (geography or music) and do not have any other as Humnity/arts
      When max(case when Subject in ('geography', 'music') then 0 else 1 end) = 0
      then 'Humanity/arts'

      -- has (Math or Economics) and do not have any other as EconomicsEngineering
      When max(case when Subject in ('math', 'economics) then 0 else 1 end) = 0
      then 'EconomicEngineering'
      else 'Other'
    end as Type

from Student_classification
Group by cust_num
```